# Capture function name

Tags: c++, function, specifications

Given an arbitrary C++ source code that only comprises the definition of a single function, I try to capture the function's name (which can be arbitrary).

For this, I assume that there are no symbols/words between a function's name and its argument list, i.e., I'm looking for the first occurrence of the bracket symbol "`(`" (which initiate the function's argument list) and capture the word in front of it (of which I think it is the function's name); is this proceeding correct?

Unfortunately, the C++ specification (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf p. 207) is incomprehensible for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for the first occurrence of the bracket symbol "(" (which initiate the function's argument list) and capture the word in front of it (of which I think it is the function's name); is this proceeding correct?

No, it is no correct. In the most basic cases, this is true:

```
int foo() {
    return 1;
}
```

But if you want to support *any* function (non-template), then it will fail for this case:

```
std::function<int(int)> foo() {
    return [](int) { return 1; };
}
```

Checking for the whitespace between the return type and the function name is also a bad idea, because most whitespaces are ignored by the compiler, i.e. this will fail:

```
std::function< int ( int ) > foo( ) {
    return [](int) { return 1; };
}
```

So, how do you do it then? **You would need to build a partial C++ parser to analyze the function definition.**

You have no other way to support *every* non-template function, and if you add the template functions, it will be even harder. The return type can include any character, there is no special delimiter available.

<sub>You can also have function pointers, which are built-in the language and break the whitespace + bracket search below. You will need to build a parser :(</sub>

<strike>To simplify, you could disallow any `#include` statements, which would only result in basic functions like the first one. If that is the case, instead of checking for the `(` symbol and getting the word before, why not find the first whitespace and get everything between the whitespace and the `(`?</strike>

```
std::string get_function_name(std::string source) {
    auto whitespace = source.find(' ');
    if (whitespace == std::string::npos)
        return "";

    auto open_bracket = source.find('(', whitespace); // find ( after whitespace
    if (open_bracket == std::string::npos)
        return "";

    return source.substr(whitespace + 1, open_bracket - whitespace);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Function return types can be very weird, e.g.

```
void foo(int t){}

void (* returnFptr())(int t){
    return foo;
}
```

The return type of `returnFptr()` is `void(*)(int)`. Thus the first opening bracket is not guaranteed to be between the function name and the parameter list.